# Nested For Loop runs painfully slow and doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have scans for matches and does several things:

1. First, it checks that appointment dates are on or after the request date of testing.
2. Then, it makes sure the cell for the request isn't empty by making sure the exact code of the request is there (there are 6 columns for testing codes).
3. Then, it makes sure the account number of the request and appointment are the same.

Below are several conditions:

- If there is an appointment on or after the request date with the requested service, it should do nothing and move on to the next row.
- If there is missing appointments for services requested, it should highlight the cells yellow.
- If the request slot on Sheet C is blank, the code should do nothing.
- If the request slot is filled, but there is an appointment on or after the request date, for the same account #, and the request type/appointment type match, the code should do nothing.
- If there isn't, the request row should be highlighted in yellow.

**Problem**

Aside from highlighting them in red, which I can deal with, the code seems to highlight ALL the rows, instead of highlighting just the ones with services requested but missing appointments.

The sheet for requests is C, and the sheet of ALL appointments scheduled is B. A nice touch would be to limit the `For` loops to only rows that contain data to make the process finish quicker (maybe add a progress bar? Excel and the VBA window both display not responding but the machines fans go faster so I know it's definitely doing something).

**Data**

To make things slightly easier:

- On Sheet C (Request Sheet):

  ```
  Account # = Column A

  Request Date = Column G

  Request Type = Columns H-M
  ```
- On Sheet B (Master Appointment Sheet):

  ```
  Account # = Column A (Must match Sheet C Column A)

  Appointment Date = Column L (Must be >= (Greater or equal) to Sheet C Column G

  Appointment Type = Column P (Must match Sheet C Column H-M)
  ```

**Code**

```
Sub check_for_copies()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For j = 2 To 1000

For i = 2 To 10000

    If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 8).Value = "CR15" And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 8).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 8).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If


    If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 9).Value = "TR15" And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 9).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 10).Value = "EEG60" And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 10).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 10).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If


    If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 11).Value = "EMG15" And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 11).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 11).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If


    If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 12).Value = "NV30" And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 12).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 12).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If


    If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 13).Value = "NV45" And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 13).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 13).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

Next

Next

End Sub
```

The code is painfully slow and looks as if it's crashing excel. I've tried adding

```
Application.Calculation = false
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
Application.EnableEvents = false
```

but it doesn't seem to help!

Comment: I haven't read through the question yet, but just looking at your code, you are doing `1000*10000` loops, or `10,000,000`. So you are performing `120,000,000` conditional statements (if, elseif) and changing the color index on a cell probably around `10,000,000` times as well. I think your entire approach to solving your problem needs some rethinking.

Comment: It should only color the rows up to 1000 times, but is there any way to make this code run in under 10 minutes? It runs for a VERY long time but it still highlights everything, which is the biggest issue I am facing right now, the speed can be slow.

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting, based on a formula?

Comment: Could I do that using a macro? How would I translate 1 If loop to that? I would be able to translate it to the rest of the if loops but have no idea how to get started.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the 1,000 and 10,000 iterations?  From what you describe, it sounds like you should know how many rows you are iterating over and limit your loops to just the number of rows in your sheets.  By your logic, sheet C always has 1,000 rows and sheet B always has 10,000 rows.  You should only be iterating over the actual number of rows in each sheet and not just large number that makes sure that you cover everything.

Comment: There are 498 rows in Sheet C currently, and 8954 in Sheet B, but I need the For loop maximums to be dynamic, because there might be more/less rows in either sheet on any given instance of this macro. My workaround for this was selecting large numbers that I knew the amount of rows would not surpass.

Comment: You could also try doing a "Find" using the value in Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7) and then iterating over that result set.  Doing so would eliminate most of the checks that will result in a negative result.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? The find function doesn't seem to be able to find values equal to or greater than, just equal to.

I am also open to the conditional formatting approach, but I have no idea how to incorporate multiple if statements to that.

Comment: To get the actual number of rows in a sheets use: Sheets("C").UsedRange.Rows.Count (using the actual sheetname of course).  This will limit the number of rows to exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider avoiding nested `For` loops and run set-based operations such as tables in a relational database or data sets/data frames in analysis tools such as SAS, SPSS, Stata, Python's Pandas, R, Julia, and others. This allows you to merge or join these two sets of data by *account number* and *request type* and run any vectorized column operation much more efficient than iterative looping. However, you could run Excel's `INDEX...MATCH` but requires arrays or array formula for conditional date comparisons and missing values.

Fortunately, if you use Excel for Windows, you can interface with the JET/ACE SQL Engine (.dll files) where you can join the two sheets of workbook and create a needed column as indicator for highlighting. Note: because Excel is not a database and hence does not conform to data integrity rules, be sure to format each column in a single data type (no mixing types), especially make date columns actual dates or leave blank, otherwise below logic will not work.

---

**SQL** *(turning `If` conditions to nested `IIF` or `CASE` in other RDBMS)*

Adjust actual column and sheet names as needed.

```sql
SELECT c.*, b.*, 
       IIF((b.[Appointment Date] >= c.[Request Date]) OR (c.[Request Date] IS NULL), 0,
           IIF(b.[Appointment Date] IS NULL, 1,
               IIF((b.[Appointment Date] < c.[Request Date]), 1, 0)
               )
           ) AS [highlight]                      
FROM [SheetC$] c
INNER JOIN [SheetB$] b
   ON c.[Account #] = b.[Account #] AND c.[Request Type] = b.[Appointment Type]
```

Alternatively and ideally, import the two sheets in an actual database (or aforementioned analysis tool) like Excel's sibling, MS Access, and run same SQL query and have Access dump results back into Excel for highlighting purposes or keep in Access and run [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/highlight-data-with-conditional-formatting-7f7c0bd4-7c37-421d-adad-a260125c8129) on a form or report!

---

**VBA** *(runs above query and dumps query output in an existing, blank Results worksheet)*

Use computed highlight row (with values 0 or 1) in *Results* sheet for yellow row highlighting.

```
Sub RunSQL()    
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRINGS (DRIVER VERSION COMMENTED OUT)
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = "SELECT c.*, b.*, " _
           &  "     IIF((b.[Appointment Date] >= c.[Request Date]) OR (c.[Request Date] IS NULL), 0, " _
           &  "         IIF(b.[Appointment Date] IS NULL, 1, " _
           &  "             IIF((b.[Appointment Date] < c.[Request Date]), 1, 0) " _
           &  "             ) " _
           &  "        ) AS [highlight]  " _                     
           &  " FROM [SheetC$] c " _
           &  " INNER JOIN [SheetB$] b " _
           &  "    ON c.[Account #] = b.[Account #] AND c.[Request Type] = b.[Appointment Type]"  

    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    With Worksheet("Results")
        For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
           .Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Next i        
       ' DATA ROWS
       .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End With

    rst.Close: conn.Close    
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am so lost, I am an excel vba newbie and have never worked with SQL. I will try to figure out your answer though, how do I start?

Comment: If running Excel in Windows, simply run VBA macro. Adjust Sheet namrs and columns in SQL string as needed.